# htaccess filesmatch Regex - How to use regex in filesmatch to match index[1-999].htm?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to put a line in my htaccess file that allows index1.htm index2.htm all the way to 999. Below did not work.

```
<FilesMatch "^/index[1-999]?\.htm$">
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I though it would be simple enough. Looks like I am the simple one.

I have been looking around in StackOverflow and found some similar code which I attempted to adapt above to no avail.

Now, I do have this which works:

```
<FilesMatch "\d{1,3}\.htm?$"> ##1 to three digits
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

BUT, how would I adapt it (prepend) to include the characters 'index' (and only those not 'sindex' or 'some-index') So matches '`index+[1 to 3 digits]+.htm`' .

Help?

Comment: `\d{1,3}\.htm?$` is going to match some bad things like `0.htm` or `0.ht` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex that matches your requested pattern:

```
^index[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.htm$
```

**Description:** Match `index`, followed by a digit `1` to `9`, followed optionally by one or two digits `0` to `9`, followed by `.htm`.

Your key mistake is the expression `[1-999]`. The brackets are used to express a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html), not an integer range.

Here's a Perl program that demonstrates this regex on a sample data set. (Also see the [live demo](http://ideone.com/6IPP94).)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    if (/^index[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.htm$/) {
        print "* [$_]\n";
    } else {
        print "  [$_]\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
index0.htm
index1.htm
index2.htm
index2.html
sindex1.htm
some-index1.htm
index11.htm
index111.htm
index999.htm
index1000.htm
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  [index0.htm]
* [index1.htm]
* [index2.htm]
  [index2.html]
  [sindex1.htm]
  [some-index1.htm]
* [index11.htm]
* [index111.htm]
* [index999.htm]
  [index1000.htm]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ranges don't work like that.

```
^/index[1-9][0-9]{,2}\.htm$
```